# If you're the smartest person on earth, how do you know if you're making logic errors?

Tags: logic, epistemology, proof

In any logical argument, there is the practical step of verifying that it is sound. When there are experts in that particular area, they can check the argument for soundness. For two examples:

- A math student can easily be graded by a teacher who has mastery of the subject.
- There are some math proofs that can be automatically checked, because
  experts have trained computers how to check them.

However, when an expert (the "smartest" person in a particular field) puts forward a new argument at the forefront of knowledge in that field, there is no super-expert who can check that argument.

How can such an argument be checked? How can the wisest person be checked for whether he or she is making a mistake? If you're the smartest person on earth, how do you know if you're making logic errors?

Comment: Perhaps it's not really clear what "smart" means in this question?  For instance, a computer could probably work through a proof in logical form and identify a mistake, but that's not to say it would necessarily be able to explain the problem to you.

Comment: this reminds me of a quote by [Brian Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan), one of the developers of Unix - _"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."_

Comment: @johnvkumpf Made an attempt at editing

Comment: @JamesKingsbery excellent! (A _little_ sad; I liked the personal touch relating to our shared experience of being corrected, but no biggie.) I can't tell from what you wrote whether your talking about "logic", "reasoning" or "math" and whether they're all the same or all different. However this does greatly clarify what I was asking.

Comment: Obviously, feel free to edit, it's your question :-)

Comment: What happened to all the comments, including the one about Fermat's Last Theorem solved by Andrew Wiles? That was the best comment to illustrate the point. I dont get it.

Comment: Do you mean how do you know you don't just think you're the smartest person because you have your own definition of smart and everyone is the best in their own way? For example, I believe that at the Church of the Transfiguration games night, I believe there were 2 kids who were brother and sister who were really good at table hockey. They could consider themselves above 95 percentile because they're good at table hockey but only table hockey is the thing they like being good at because they're interested in it. Do you mean something like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking strictly about logic as commonly understood, there are wholly mechanical procedures to accurately, consistently and comprehensively evaluate any standard argument.  Therefore, I'm going to assume you mean this more in general: how do you, as the hypothetical smartest person in the world, recognize when you are in error?

- The community tells you: Just as a library can have more knowledge than any given person, a community of people may be able to discern things that an individual smart person, no matter how bright, might be able to discern. (Of course, groups as a whole can also be dumber than any individual within the group).
- The universe tells you:  You can have a belief you are absolutely committed to, and it runs hard up against reality.
- God tells you: Obviously your opinion about this one depends on your religious beliefs, but if you are a religious person, you might pray for discernment.

In general, if you adopt an attitude of humility and openmindedness, it becomes more likely that either some combination of the above will enlighten you or that you will simply advance in your thinking to where you can perceive your wrongness.

Comment: I would vote up your answer @chrisSunami if I had enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

It is a logic error to assume that people who are "smarter" always detect logic errors that those "less smart" will overlook.

Therefore, you know the same way as always: you catch yourself, or someone else catches them and tells you.  (You might have to wait a little longer or have a few more people check if you've already done a pretty good job of reasoning correctly and thus caught the easier-to-detect errors.)

Comment: I think this is a valid point. Less "smart" people can find errors in "smarter" people's work. Perhaps I should clarify "the smartest person on earth working at the leading edge of your ability" so you barely understand what you're doing?

Comment: @johnvkumpf - I don't think that changes the answer.  If nobody cares enough, you're on your own (just like you would be if you were of any "smartness" and nobody was checking your work).  If many people do, they will spot errors you didn't.

Comment: You make a blanket statement "they will spot errors you didn't." I disagree. You need to defend that, not just state it.

Comment: @johnvkumpf - As an example, thorough peer review catches errors in even the most stellar scientists' manuscripts.  (Often peer review is not so thorough, unfortunately, or the reviewers are too awed by the reputation of the person whose article they are reviewing.)

Comment: Ok. It's possible. Not certain, but possible. But it helps clarify the question even further: "The smartest person on earth doing work that no one else understands". Altho the question's been closed, and I'm not sure this clarification will re-open it. I think I would re-set this question atop the current view of epistemology to have a chance at re-opening.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you're the smartest person, then that's one way to know you've made a logic error.

Kidding.

Socrates famously was the smartest person because claimed to know nothing.

I read yesterday (sometimes I don't notice the obvious) that rational starts with ratio.

Maybe being rational is all about weighing different probabilities, and keeping some balance, rather than making claims with 100% certainty.

But you asked about logic errors, which could be different if only concerned with the validity of logic. Not rationality,  per se. In that case, the smartest person should encode their logic in a computer program and see if it compiles and executes properly. Far more reliable than human minds. In the realm of pure logic anyways.

Comment: Hm. There's a good point in here, but I'm not sure I necessarily agree with your prescription.  Even if I program my argument in logical form and the computer says yes, does this necessarily support the argument I was presenting in its prelogical form?  Can I be convinced that I've programmed the argument correctly? etc.

Comment: You can be convinced it has a valid logical form. The last paragraph is meant to make the point "errors of logic" (which was the specific wording in the question) and "errors of reasoning" can be two different things (roughly equating to validity and soundness).

Comment: The word "logic" has several meanings. It's not entirely clear that the OP means it in the strict sense of formal logic or if he means "reasoning".

Comment: Indeed. So I addressed them both.

Comment: Could you make your answerer clearer then? I don't see based on the structure how you're clearly addressing both

Comment: If you want to avoid errors of rationality, avoid making claims with 100% certainty. If you want to avoid errors of logical form, use a compiler. If your logic is wrong, either it won't compile or it won't run right.

Comment: I would up-vote this for the humor (if i had enuf rep)

Comment: I agree with @PaulRoss that the process of transcribing your thinking to a computer program is another source of errors that you have to prove you have not made. I think this might just move the problem around, not solve it.

Comment: How many programs have you written? I've written a million or so. You usually start with an idea, and soon realize that idea doesn't work. The compiler doesn't lie. I'm not saying philosophers do, but they are far more fallible.

Comment: I'm a programmer. And i have seen 1. People code the same mis-understanding in their mind into the code. 2. Bugs in the code that have been there for years, after several experts have reviewed the code several times, then are somehow discovered.

Comment: I've seen those things too. My suggestion is to use a compiler instead of just the brain if you aim to detect "logic errors". It is not fool proof, that is also true.

Answer (score 0):

“However, when an expert (the "smartest" person in a particular field) puts forward a new argument at the forefront of knowledge in that field, there is no super-expert who can check that argument.”

For the hard sciences, the truth or falsehood of an original statement is (at least in principle) objective and independent of the person who is making the statement. These statements can be validated by anyone with sufficient training. The talent (that which makes one the smartest person in a given filed) in this case lies not in the ability to verify the new statement, but in the manner in which it was discovered. As an example take relativity: Once Einstein discovered the principles of special relativity, a lot of other people were able to validate his ideas. His genius was in the WAY he was able come up with those principles, not in the principles themselves.

Keep in mind also that the opposite situation can happen: It has been the case that mediocre scientists stumble across major results or insights. That they themselves aren’t the brightest light in their given filed doesn’t in anyway diminish the significance of their results. Josephson of the Josephson effect fame is a notorious case.

Comment: I think your point is valid--that the smartest person in a field _can_ come up with novel statements that others can validate. But not always, and that's the case we're addressing here. Einstein is (almost) a good point. I'm not sure I agree that "a lot" of other people can understand it. Isn't it generally accepted that special relativity is "very hard to understand"? What if it was a little harder to understand?

Comment: @johnvkumpf Although conceivable, maybe that case is not possible. The closest case to it is Newton, who had to invent a new branch of math, calculus, in order to explain his physics, and yet people still understood him.

Comment: Well, I think there are two scenarios. Science is littered with people who discover/invent things that no one ever thought of before, and when they do, everyone understands. However in the cases of Andrew Wiles solving Fermat's Last Theorem and Brian Kernighan on debugging code, they both are close to what i'm suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

Checking for consistency in analysis is pretty much universal technique of finding logical errors. It doesn't change for how smart or stupid one is.

Teachers grading students are not necesarily smarter or more correct than the students. Teachers can be wrong. There are deliciously documented cases of how Maxwell & Einstein were not only more correct than their teachers but that the whole world, or almost, eventually accepted it.

At research level, the experts are peer reviewed. Which means that experts judge the research work of each other. Even if some researcher is highest rated, he could be judged to be wrong. Einstein's views on Quantum Mechanics have been judged as incorrect even though he was supposed to be the smartest Physicist across multiple generations.

Comment: Can you say more? What if there's a particularly complicated thing where logic errors are subtle?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @James How does majorness or minorness of an error in logic have any effect on method of detecting it?